# to mock a list using mock library 1.0.1

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

there is a `patch.dict` function for mocking a dictionary. Is it possible to mock a list with the mock 1.0.1 library? I am not going to call on the mocked object, so `side_effect` would not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special method for lists like there is for dicts, but you can use the general [patch](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch) method:

```
from mock import patch
foo = ['original', 'stuff']
with patch('__main__.foo', new=['mocked', 'items']):
    assert foo == ['mocked', 'items']
assert foo == ['original', 'stuff']
```

Note that the first argument to `patch` is a string with the full Python path to the item you want to patch. If your list is as module scope, you can use `'package.module.<list name>'`.